# Как можно увеличить значение символа в JS

Tags: javascript, символы

Можно ли как, допустим, в C++ применить какие-то операции с символом, чтобы он шёл дальше по алфавиту?

Например:

```
char sym = 'a';
sym++; // sym = 'b'
sym++; // sym = 'c'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function nextSymbol(a) {
  return String.fromCharCode(a.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
}

console.log(nextSymbol('a'));
console.log(nextSymbol('г'));
console.log(nextSymbol('Ц'));

var a = 'а';
for (var i = 1; i <= 33; i++) {
  console.log(i, a);
  a = nextSymbol(a);
}
console.log(i, a);
```

Comment: А не подскажите, как с русскими символами манипулировать? Просто я знаю, что в ASCII, буквы российского алфавита очень странно разбросаны. Можно ли с ними какую-то операцию совершить или это уже в программе самой решать надо?

Comment: @Pon4iPay "буквы российского алфавита очень странно разбросаны" - ??

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ2eg.jpg . Взгляните на кодировку русских букв. Если английские ровно идут одина за другой, то на букве "п" (175) обрывается порядок и идут другие символы, а русский алфавит продолжается уже на коде 224

Comment: а, странно... ну ладно, спасибо!

Comment: @Pon4iPay Единственная "странность" - с буквой "ё".

Comment: Это да. Но все же любят её на 'е' заменять, неправда ли?)

Answer (score 1):

Варианты с `charCode` будут работать, только если ожидаются символы, вмещающиеся в два байта. Для поддержки всего Юникода (включая эмодзи и т.д.), нужно немного изменить. Разницу можно увидеть, если запустить этот код в консоли браузера или любом другом инструменте, отображающем эмодзи. Правильный код должен позволить перейти от эмодзи коня к эмодзи барашка.

```js
'use strict';

function nextSymbolLegacy(a) { return String.fromCharCode(a.charCodeAt(0) + 1); }

function nextSymbolNew(a) { return String.fromCodePoint(a.codePointAt(0) + 1); }

const horse = '\u{1F40E}';
const ram  = '\u{1F40F}';

console.log(horse);
console.log(ram);

console.log(nextSymbolLegacy(horse));
console.log(nextSymbolNew(horse));
```

Функция с `charCode` будет выводить символ со знаком вопроса, обозначающий осиротевший символ из суррогатной пары.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]